# Display WinForm when WebBrowser control finished loading

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, delay, flicker

I have WinForm with WebBrowser control inside.

I am facing an annoying flicker from WebBrowser control. This is manifested that the body of WebBrowser control (or background) is shown for about 200ms before the web page is loaded and I could not get rid of it.

I want, when call myForm.Show() to see the window when WebBrowser completely finished loading and not to see this flickering.

Is there some way when calling myForm.Show() to display the WebForm page at the moment when WebBrowser control finished loading the page completely?

I know about DocumentCompleted event and read and tried some tricks [mentioned here](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2010/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-flicker-on-windows-forms-applications.aspx) but still can not get rid of this filled blank background before web page is shown.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    WebBrowser _Webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
    TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    public MyForm(string url)
    {
        _Webbrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        this.Controls.Add(_Webbrowser);
        _Webbrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => { _tcs.TrySetResult(null); };
        _Webbrowser.Navigate(url);
    }

    public async new void Show()
    {
        await _tcs.Task;
        base.Show();
    }
}
```